# What is the rdsadmin user and should I care?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've inherited control of an AWS MySQL RDS instance. I'm curious to know what the 'rdsadmin' user is and whether I should know the password for this or whether this is purely for use by the Amazon Web Console.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is Amazon's own user that is used by Amazon to perform updates, run backups and do other maintenance tasks. That said, Amazon's support should be able to advise you.

In general, you don't need to (and should not) know the password.

Comment: This actually conflicts with what I have been told on the AWS IRC channel. Also, there is the option 'New Master Password:' when modifying an instance. Which user is that for?

Comment: "New Master Password" will reset the password for the named admin user that you created when you spun up the RDS instance, which is a separate account than 'rdsadmin'. What was said on IRC?

Comment: ok, thanks. Can I find out the name of the 'named admin user'? I did not create the instance. From IRC - "rdsadmin account is the equivilant of the default 'root' account"

Comment: You can check the named admin user's username in the AWS console - it will be in the "Configuration Details" panel of the instance details, and will be titled "User name". The "rdsadmin" user is for Amazon's usage, and the user mentioned here is for your usage. Of course you are free to create other users, but this one is the only one granted with full admin rights.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the rdsadmin password without instantiating a new db?

Comment: @Muhatashim no, because you should never know the `rdsadmin` user's password.

Comment: I understand that it's not possible to read the password, but it seems like you can change its password. I ended up restoring back to a different snapshot because of it.

Comment: @Muhatashim I cannot stress this enough - you should *never* need to know, use, change or otherwise interact with the `rdsadmin` user.